# /etc/cron.daily/aide script uses all space in /run

Tags: 18.04

I have a problem with aide on one of my servers.

I've installed it on Ubuntu 18.04 via apt.

With everything else there is cron script installed in `/etc/cron.daily/aide`.

This script creates temporary `cron.daily.*` directories in `/run/aide`. After a week of daily cron runs this directories use all the space under `/run` mount point:

```
root@my-server:/run# df -h /run 
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
tmpfs 796M 796M 0 100% /run

root@my-server:/run# du -sch * | grep -vE '^0|K' 
794M aide 
1.3M udev 
796M total

root@my-server:/run# du -sch aide/* | grep -vE '^0|K'
99M aide/cron.daily
100M aide/cron.daily.old.1MV71MCH2b
100M aide/cron.daily.old.6Vli33Nc11
99M aide/cron.daily.old.CECwDp5c8s
100M aide/cron.daily.old.HxbiTwfaIW
100M aide/cron.daily.old.lZEPrqsxkR
794M total
```

I couldn't find any information on how I can configure it in aide configuration files. The one workaround I've found is to mount `/run/aide` as separate tmpfs. But I don't think that's how it is supposed to work.

If someone knows how to tweak number and/or size of this directories, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had done a default installation and found the same problem.

## Reason for the issue

=
/etc/cron.daily/aide takes the temporary location /run/aide

```
TMPBASE="/run/aide"
$ grep -n TMPBASE /etc/cron.daily/aide
41:TMPBASE="/run/aide"
42:LOCKFILE="$TMPBASE/cron.daily.lock"
43:TMPDIRIN="$TMPBASE/cron.daily"
55:# make sure $TMPBASE exists
57:if ! [ -d "$TMPBASE" ]; then
58:  mkdir -p $TMPBASE
59:  chown root:root $TMPBASE
60:  chmod 600 $TMPBASE
617:    if ! NEWNAME="$(mktemp -d $TMPBASE/cron.daily.old.XXXXXXXXXX)"; then
```

## Solution

### To stop /run getting full

#Step 1: Remove the execute permission

```
chmod a-x /etc/cron.daily/aide
```

Step 2: Make the script permission immutable (so that updates to aide does not affect the script permission)

```
chattr +i /etc/cron.daily/aide
```

### To continue using aide as a cron

Step 3: Add below command into your cron:

```
aide --config=/etc/aide/aide.conf --check
```

Step Bonus:

Remove */run* and its child directories and files from your config file (*/etc/aide/aide.conf*) so that dynamic files are not scanned to save your CPU

Comment: Thanks for the that Nmath :)

Comment: Isn't change the TMPBASE var in `/etc/cron.daily/aide` enough to solve the issue?